# Use of three20 framework in ios programming

Tags: ios, three20

I am working on old project there use of three20 framework but i don,t know about three20, So please tell me about it deeply?
what will we can use instead of three20 in current time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old [Three20 GitHub](https://github.com/facebookarchive/three20/tree/v1.1) project is still available, with all of the code and samples still intact on a different branch.

See the "Articles" folder for documentation, and "samples" for sample projects.

Answer (score 3):

I've also fondly used Three20 on numerous projects and tried hanging on to it for a while.  However, iOS8 causes numerous runtime errors / crashes on my Three20 projects.  It's actually surprising to see how much functionality still works but you're strongly advised to not use it.  There's no real community behind it anymore and no one is maintaining / supporting it.

I'm migrating to NimbusKit - it's developed by some of the original developers of Three20.  They also have a good [migration guide](http://wiki.nimbuskit.info/Three20-Migration-Guide).

Comment: Hey, do you know how to fix this error?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043720/three20the-three20-framework-of-the-source-code-error